# Can I use Blender to find and separate a loop from a video?

Tags: video

I have a video file that has a looping animation over a background image. It is nearly impossible to find the loop with the naked eye. Can Blender, or another tool, detect this loop and cut it out as a separate video file?

Comment: I don't know a tool having that feature but maybe if you show the animation, some ideas to help you could come to mind...

Comment: @m.ardito https://youtu.be/Tazx_vCZCv4?t=9
My goal is to set it as an animated background on my desktop, but I'd like to lower the file size by just having the loop. I had thought maybe Blender could identify a couple frames that were identical and then I could go from there.

Comment: I've seen the video (?) but I can't see any loop... you wrote "a video file that has a looping animation", but I'm not sure it's so...  even background moving clouds seem not repeating in a loop, let alone particles...

Comment: Huh, I'm fairly certain I saw a couple loops, but if not oh well. I'd still be interested in learning how to perform this task in the future, perhaps by programmatically finding identical frames in a video.

Comment: if you're sure, here is an idea on how to check: open the video in blender VSE, render it to image sequence, then use a duplicate file finder (depending on your OS). If there are two identical frames, their files shodul be equal...